# Save image CefSharp [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a little problem with my new browser using CefSharp WinForms in VB.NET. Ive got a right-click context menu and i want to add the option "Save image as...". How can i save the image right-clicked in cefsharp?

Have a nice day!

Comment: See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_IContextMenuHandler.htm you can add your own menu items, look at the source for a more detailed example, you can get the url and download the image yourself

Comment: I already have a contextmenu but i just dont know how to download the image via the link i get. Getting the link is not a problem the biggest problem for me is to download the image via DownloadHandler or something. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Next time please include what you already have. http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_StartDownload.htm

Comment: For future reference the `API` is searchable.